# How do I pass arguments while loading any modules in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, visual-studio-code, loadmodule

I have a module in typescript which contains the following code.

```
export class Account {
constructor(app: any) {
    this.initialize(app);
  }

private initialize(app: any) {
    app.get("/login", (req: any, res: any) => {
        res.render("index", { user: req.user });
    });

    app.get("/logout", (req: any, res: any) => {
        res.render("index", { user: req.user });
    });
}
```

}

And I want to load this module in main file. like

`require('/mymodule')(app)`

How I can do this in typescript ?

Comment: I don't think you could. You exported a `Class constructor` hence it cannot be invoked without `new`

Comment: Yes, this was an option but I want it like I mentioned in the above code

Answer (score 1):

> `require('/mymodule')(app)`

Proper way:

```
import {Account} from './mymodule';
new Account(app);
```

## More

Just some free docs

- Read up on classes : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/docs/classes.html
- Read up on modules : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/docs/project/modules.html

Comment: Thanks @basarat for answering, I am already using the same approach but as per the tslint rule it's an unused-expression.